# Split new-lines into separate keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{'movies': ["1.\nBram Stoker's Dracula\n(1992)",
  '2.\nDracula\n(1931)',
  '3.\nHotel Transylvania\n(2012)',
  '4.\nBlade: Trinity\n(2004)',
  '5.\nDracula Untold\n(2014)',
  '6.\nThe Monster Squad\n(1987)',
  '7.\nNosferatu\n(1922)',
  '8.\nHotel Transylvania 3\n(2018)',
  '9.\nHotel Transylvania 2\n(2015)']}
```

I wanted to split this dictionary into two separate keys for example, as:

```
#expected output
{'movies': ["Bram Stoker's Dracula",
  "Dracula" ...], 'year':[1992, 1931 ...]}
```

I have tried this which was supposed to select for strings belonging after `\n`:

```
result = {}
for k,v in movies.items():
    result[k] = movies[k].lower().replace(' ', '_').split('\n')
```

but I get the error:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: The expected output is invalid syntax, could you correct it without shorcuts to be clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`movies` is a list not a dict:

Suppose this input:

```
d1 = {'movies': ["1.\nBram Stoker's Dracula\n(1992)",
  '2.\nDracula\n(1931)',
  '3.\nHotel Transylvania\n(2012)',
  '4.\nBlade: Trinity\n(2004)',
  '5.\nDracula Untold\n(2014)',
  '6.\nThe Monster Squad\n(1987)',
  '7.\nNosferatu\n(1922)',
  '8.\nHotel Transylvania 3\n(2018)',
  '9.\nHotel Transylvania 2\n(2015)']}
```

Create a dict to store your extracted data:

```
d2 = {'movies': [], 'year': []}
for row in d1['movies']:
    _, movie, year = row.split('\n')
    d2['movies'].append(movie)
    d2['year'].append(int(year[1:-1]))
```

*No test is done. I guess all lines have the same format*

Result output:

```
>>> d2
  'Dracula',
  'Hotel Transylvania',
  'Blade: Trinity',
  'Dracula Untold',
  'The Monster Squad',
  'Nosferatu',
  'Hotel Transylvania 3',
  'Hotel Transylvania 2'],
 'year': [1992, 1931, 2012, 2004, 2014, 1987, 1922, 2018, 2015]}
```

**Update**
A more robust version with regex:

```
import re

d2 = {'movies': [], 'year': []}
for row in d1['movies']:
    sre = re.search(r'\d\.\n(.*)(?:\n?\((\d+)\))?', row)
    movie = sre.group(1)
    year = int(sre.group(2)) if sre.group(2) else float('nan')
    d2['movies'].append(movie)
    d2['year'].append(year)
```

Comment: I seem to get the following error when I run it on my script which follows the same sequence as the list but with 50 values; The error ```not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)``` at the second line of the for-loop ```_, movie, year = row.split('\n')```

Comment: I think that I found the error, one of the rows is missing an extra ```\n```, is there a way to fill the corresponding row in the year column with a value such as ```N/A``` when this happens?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to solve this kind of pattern-matching task. In the example below, the title and year are [captured in groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#grouping).

```
import re

movie_pattern = re.compile(r"[0-9]+\.\n([^\n]+)\n\(([0-9]+)\)")

movies_dict = {
    ...
}

split_dict = {"titles": [], "years": []}

for movie in movies_dict["movies"]:
    match = movie_pattern.fullmatch(movie)

    split_dict["titles"].append(match[1])
    split_dict["years"].append(int(match[2]))

print(split_dict)
```

Explanation:

`[0-9]+\.`: One or more digits representing the index, followed by a literal `.`

`\n`: Literal `\n`

`([^\n]+)`: One or more non-newline characters representing the title, in a capture group

`\n`: Literal `\n`

`\(`: Literal `(`

`([0-9]+)`: One or more digits representing the year, in a capture group

`\)`: Literal `)`

---

**Edit**: to handle the case you mention in your comment, where the year is sometimes missing, you can use the following pattern instead:

```
movie_pattern = re.compile(r"[0-9]+\.\n([^\n]+)(?:\n\(([0-9]+)\))?")
```

The `(?:)` is a non-capturing group, and the `?` afterwards signifies that the group is optional.

Then, if the year is missing, the value of the capture group is `None`, which you can handle like so:

```
for movie in movies_dict["movies"]:
    match = movie_pattern.fullmatch(movie)

    title = match[1]
    year = match[2]

    if year is not None:
        year = int(year)

    split_dict["titles"].append(title)
    split_dict["years"].append(year)
```

So if `movies_dict` looks like

```
movies_dict = {
    "movies": [
        ..., 
        "9.\nHotel Transylvania 2",  # only one newline, no year
    ],
}
```

then the output will be

```
{
    "titles": [..., "Hotel Transylvania 2"],
    "years": [..., None],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here is a solution as a list comprehension (assuming `movies_dict` as input):

```
dict(zip(['movies', 'year'], zip(*[(a, int(b[1:-1]))
                                    for i in movies_dict['movies']
                                    for a,b in [i.split('\n')[1:]]
                                   ])))
```

output:

```
{'movies': ("Bram Stoker's Dracula",
  'Dracula',
  'Hotel Transylvania',
  'Blade: Trinity',
  'Dracula Untold',
  'The Monster Squad',
  'Nosferatu',
  'Hotel Transylvania 3',
  'Hotel Transylvania 2'),
 'year': (1992, 1931, 2012, 2004, 2014, 1987, 1922, 2018, 2015)}
```